# Swift word count fatal error

Tags: swift, uitextview, word-count

I am working on a word count function in textViewDidChange. As soon as I type it crashes. When I paste in a sentence, the debugger shows it is getting the word count, but it is crashing when adding the count to the button title with a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    let wordCount = textView.text.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).count
    let words = String(format: "%d", wordCount)

    countButton.title = "\(words)"
}
```

Comment: Check that your `countButton` IBOutlet is properly connected.

Comment: What is `count ` in the last code line?

Comment: It was a typo, changed it to words. The countButton is created programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `countButton` is non-`nil` (check the outlet connection).

Also, the variable in your string interpolation, `count`, does not seem to be defined - maybe an ivar that is still `nil`?

**Edit**:

As it turns out, your `countButton` is in fact `nil` and programmatically created. I suspect a definition like so:

```
weak var countButton : UIButton!
```

As well as an initialization like so:

```
self.countButton = UIButton()
```

The problem is then, that the `weak` modifier tells the system to not hold ownership of the object. Thus, it immediately gets deallocated after creation.

Try this instead:

```
let button = UIButton()
self.view?.addSubview(button)
self.countButton = button
```

Comment: Well, @matt is right about the warning part of your question, which I opted to ignore: you never change `wordCount`, so it doesn't need to be mutable.

Comment: The button is indeed coming up nil.         `if countButton != nil {
            countButton.title = "Word Count:\(words)"
        } else {
            print("countButton is nil")
        }`The button is created programmatically in an inputAccessoryView, and I've created the Outlet.

Comment: If it is programmatically created, make sure ARC does not bite your ass by instantly deallocating it before you add it as a subview.

Comment: On creation, assign it to a local let, add it as a subview ad then assign your instance variable in the same scope.

Comment: @mrcrowley, I did modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: That did the trick! I upvoted your answer.

Comment: You may also accept it, you know?;)

Answer (score 0):

> The variable wordCount also has a warning saying it was never mutated, consider changing it to let. I assumed var was the was the way to go since the count would change

The count might change. But the value of the variable `wordCount` will *never* change, at least in the code *you* show. The only thing you ever do with it, having created it, is print it. Thus, it should be a `let` variable, as the compiler suggests.